# A Trivial Pursuit #09 (History 2/4): Windows 7

Tags: word, knowledge, history, mastermind, wordle

<sub>This is part 9 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

[image: Skyscraper with rows of coloured windows and clues]
<sup>*Colourblind-friendly version available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjjid.png).*</sup>

Puzzle in text format, for accessibility:

```
Total height of the Empire State Building (including antenna), in feet        [Gn] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
Year that the cathedral in Lincoln, UK, became the world's tallest building   [Gn] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
Number of steps in the Eiffel Tower                                           [Gn] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
Year that Europe's current tallest free-standing structure was completed      [Gn] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
Year of the inauguration of the Burj Khalifa                                  [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Gy]
*YEAR* [4]                                                                    [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn]
Frank ----- Wright (US, 1867)                                                 [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
----- Niemeyer (Brazil, 1907)                                                 [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gn] [Gy]
----- Piano (Italy, 1937)                                                     [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Gy] [Gy]
Zaha ----- (Iraq, 1950)                                                       [Gy] [Gn] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
César ----- (Argentina, 1926)                                                 [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy]
*COUNTRY* [5]                                                                 [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn]
Sixth and Guadalupe                                                           [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ]
Vasco da Gama Tower                                                           [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Y ]
BCEAO Tower                                                                   [Gy] [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Gn]
DC Tower 1                                                                    [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Gn] [Y ]
The Shard                                                                     [Y ] [Y ] [Y ] [Gn] [Gy] [Gy]
*CITY* [6]                                                                    [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn]
First name of architect who was born in [6] in [4] and worked in [5]          [Y ] [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Gn]
Kingdom where he was born…                                                    [Gy] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Y ] [Y ] [Y ]
…in this modern-day country                                                   [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Y ]
His naturalised surname on becoming a US citizen                              [Gn] [Y ] [Gy] [Gn] [Gy] [Gn] [Gy]
US architect under whom he worked at the start of his career                  [Gy] [Y ] [Gy] [Gy] [Y ] [Y ] [Gy]
*The relevant final answer to this puzzle*                                    [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn] [Gn]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The relevant final answer to the architectural puzzle is:

> **[Reimann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonin_Raymond)**

> The green and yellow windows of the skyscraper give us four Wordle style puzzles to solve.

> ```
>  Total height of the Empire State Building (including antenna), in feet       1454
>  Year that the cathedral in Lincoln, UK, became the world's tallest building  1311
>  Number of steps in the Eiffel Tower                                          1665
>  Year that Europe's current tallest free-standing structure was completed     1967 (The Ostankino Tower)
>  Year of the inauguration of the Burj Khalifa                                 2010
> ```
>
> From the green windows we have 1???
>  And the gray windows exclude every other digit except 8.
>  So the answer here is:
>
> ```
> YEAR [4]                                 1888
> ```
>
> [image: Stage1]

> The second group are all architects, with their dates of birth:
>
> ```
>  Frank ----- Wright (US, 1867)    Lloyd
>  ----- Niemeyer (Brazil, 1907)    Oscar
>  ----- Piano (Italy, 1937)        Renzo
>  Zaha ----- (Iraq, 1950)          Hadid
>  César ----- (Argentina, 1926)    Pelli
> ```
>
> From the green windows we have ?A?A?
>  And from the yellow windows we know we must use an N (not 3rd) and a P (not 1st).
>  And the only country that fits is:
>
> ```
> COUNTRY [5]                      JAPAN
> ```
>
> [image]

> The third group are all skyscrapers, and we want their locations.
>
> ```
>  Sixth and Guadalupe     Austin
>  Vasco da Gama Tower     Lisbon
>  BCEAO Tower             Bamako
>  DC Tower 1              Vienna
>  The Shard               London
> ```
>
> From the green windows we have ???DNO
>  And from the yellow windows we know we must use an L (not 1st), an A (not 1st or 2nd) and a K. There are also several letters excluded by the grey windows, but the known letters are enough to give us:
>
> ```
> CITY [6]                KLADNO
> ```
>
> [image]

> Finally, using the answers to the first three puzzles, we find information about Antonin Raymond (born Reimann):
>
> ```
>  First name of architect who was born in [6] in [4] and worked in [5]   Antonin
>  Kingdom where he was born…                                             Bohemia
>  …in this modern-day country                                            Czechia
>  His naturalised surname on becoming a US citizen                       Raymond
>  US architect under whom he worked at the start of his career           Gilbert (Cass Gilbert)
> ```
>
> From the green windows we have R??M?NN.
>  And from the yellow windows we know we must use an A (not 2nd), an E (not 3rd) and an I (not 2nd).
>  And that gives us:
>
> ```
> The relevant final answer to this puzzle                REIMANN
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Since the colours are lost in a text-only explanation, it may be useful to point out some parts of the deductive logic so that solvers can see how you reached the final answers in all 4 cases. Readers interested in seeing a fully coloured solution can see the one I created during testing, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahLrk.png).

Comment: @stiv I started editing the graphic but it got quite messy, so went with text. I'll steal parts of your tidy version if that's ok, and add some details for the solving logic.

Comment: Absolutely - please feel free to cannibalise my diagram as required! Definitely much easier to add text to the original Excel file it was designed in than to the image itself...

Comment: @Stiv You designed this to grate on the nerves of mathematicians who think the solution word is naught but a common misspelling, didn't you? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor that's just an unproven hypothesis.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually, there's a story in that which I will share at the end of the series!